# Javafx: How to add eventhandlers to another seperate class

Tags: user-interface, events, javafx

I have two buttons within in a pane on the scene. I have added the event handler like this:

```
    Button reset=new Button ("Reset");
        reset.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        public void handle(MouseEvent event){
        System.out.println("reseting");
        model.reset();
        Play(stage);
    }});

  Button guess=new Button ("Guess");
  guess.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        public void handle(MouseEvent event){
        ArrayList<Integer> FullGuess=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        boolean condition=true;
        for (int y:fullGuess){
           if (y==0){
              condition=false;
           }
       }
   }});
```

How can I do the event handling part in another class rather than doing it directly in the class as I have done?

Comment: Without any additional details a answerer would probably need to explain the details of OOA to you, which is outside the scope an answer.

Comment: Define your EventHandler in a separate class and pass the caller as a reference in its constructor. Then just bind it as normal via the addEventHandler method above. You can then still access all the parent caller's public methods from your externally defined class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment uses an [*anonymous class*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)  to handle events, but you can promote your anonymous handler to a [*member*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) of the enclosing class or a separate class having [*package-private*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) access. In either case, you'll want to pass the required `List<Integer>` as a parameter.

```
List<Integer> fullGuess = new ArrayList<Integer>();
…
Button guess = new Button("Guess");
guess.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new MyEventHandler(fullGuess));
```

In another file:

```
class MyEventHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

    private final List<Integer> fullGuess;

    public MyEventHandler(List<Integer> fullGuess) {
        this.fullGuess = fullGuess;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        boolean condition = true;
        for (int y : fullGuess) {
            …
        }
    }
}
```